# Why do my javascript and jquery source files consistently not load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, web

I quite frankly run into this problem every time I try to code html or anything web related.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. I try a hard refresh, doesn't work. I try changing the file name sometimes. It may work for a few. I try a new page, it doesn't work. I'm really lost on what to do here. If I create a /js folder, and stick my freaking js files in it, what can I do so that it will pick up on them every time, without fail? This isn't related to other coding mistakes, because I'm taking code directly from working examples, and they do not work because of it not picking up on the jquery source file.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have any console errors? Plus, make sure that you are loading jquery **first** before any library or js script.

Comment: Can you edit your post and paste all your .html?

Comment: If you aren't using a service to serve the webpages and are instead just throwing html files in your browser, that path is going to equate to file:///C:/jquery.js or whatever your local hard drive is.  How are you testing your web pages?

Comment: Umm, whatever guy suggested removing the first "/" from the src destination is right. It just plain works. All of these demos are meant to be run on a local hard drive, so I don't understand why they would put up non-working code like that. I'll post an example.

Comment: Are you working from your local file system? that's usually a bad idea when coding for the web. Just launch a simple webserver for localhost and always work from it.

Comment: I'll probably have to set up an apache server or something to complete the training course. As of yet, I am quite clueless on how to do so even after doing it a few times. It always seems to screw up somewhere and I'd rather learn the logic and syntax now rather than get held up on the one thing I can't get done at the moment.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is an example of where it has the front slash at the beginning. Doesn't work with it, works without it. This is with the html file being in some random directory that has a /js folder in it with the jquery.js file in it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>jQuery Selectors</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<p>Hello</p>
<p>World</p>

<div>&copy; 2011 by John Fontana</div>

<script>
$("p").css("color","#FF0000");
$("div").css("color","#000000");
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you need document ready   `<script>$(function() {  ...code here });</script>`

Comment: @RobScott What would that change here?

Comment: @TiiJ7 - not understanding your question. I was always taught to put JS in document ready function so it can fire appropriately.

Comment: @RobScott you don't always need to wait for document ready to begin executing javascript. In this case, he doesn't need it because the code comes after all the elements that it interacts with.